# Apache 2.4 i WAMP redirect from http to https not working

Tags: apache-2.4

I am using wamp server in windows(Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.12). I have successfully installed SSL certs. Now https is working without any issue. But http redirection is not working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com
Redirect permanent / https://test.com/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/test"
<Directory "C:/wamp64/www/">
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41/conf/key/fullchain.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41/conf/key/privkey.pem"
SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41/conf/key/fullchain.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

when I am trying to access it using http, I am getting bad request error.

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

Could you please help me figure out this one?